# How to find (or 'generate') combinatorial meaning for the given expression

Tags: combinatorics

$\left(\dfrac{6(k-n)(k-1)}{(n-2)(n-1)}+1\right)\dfrac{30}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$
(for $n\geq 3$ and $1\leq k \leq n$)

The expression comes from question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304876/please-help-to-find-function-for-given-inputs-and-outputs where it is used to get answer for some unknown problem (I believe that's combinatorial, with possibility of used Monte-Carlo method). The OP didn't give any interpretation of the expression.

Can you please share your best ideas about combinatorial interpretation of the expression? Big thanks in advance.

*P.S. There's tiny possibility that it was mathematical/SE joke.*

Comment: That's an expression, not a formula.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: This is just my attempt to rewrite the formula in a more appealing and symmetric way (symmetric with respect to $k$ vs $n+1-k$): $$\frac{30\Big((n+1)(n+2)-6k(n+1-k)\Big)}{(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)}$$ For all I know, this formula could be an essential component of the North Korea nuclear program. [This was discussed on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6882/technical-sanctions-against-nations-and-providing-answers-to-users-from-those-na)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post does not show a *meaning* of the expression, but explains how one might arrive at it.

I want a quadratic function with zero mean defined on $\{1,\dots,n\}$. Naturally, it should be symmetric about the midpoint of the interval. The obvious symmetric function is $k(k-n-1)$, but it does not have mean zero. The mean is 
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n k(k-n-1) = -\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$$
So I subtract that, arriving at $k(k-n-1)+\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$. But maybe I also care about the second moment, which is 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(k(k-n-1)+\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{6}\right)^2 = \frac{(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)}{180}$$
Dividing by the second moment yields
$$\frac{180}{(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)}\left(k(k-n-1)+\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{6}\right) $$
which is the formula in question.

Comment: Great answer! And actually good meaning, at least for me.